# A* PathFinding Poor Performance

Tags: ai, path-finding

I'm getting poor performance in-game due to my path-finding algorithm. The farther I get from my NPC, the worse the framerate gets.

Ok, I updated my code and implemented the openList as a min-heap and the closed list as an associative array. As far as I know, it's not possible to grow binary heaps in D so I had to allocate enough space on my openList so that my game wouldn't crash.

Unfortunately, when I fired up my game to test pathfinding, the performance was still bad, despite the openList being sorted by fScore.

I'm not entirely sure what i'm missing. As far as I've read, the main areas for performance are the data structures and the heuristic to an extent.

The heuristic i'm using is Manhattan distance, since my nodes are based upon tiles. My data structures are a min-heap, sorted by fScore, lowest at the front, and an associative array, which I believe is implemented as a hash table in D.

Where is all the performance going?

Are my data structures implemented and used right?

Would it help performance to implement tie breaking with Manhattan Distance?

```
struct Node
{
bool walkable;      //Whether this node is blocked or open
vect2 position;     //The tile's position on the map in pixels
int xIndex, yIndex; //The index values of the tile in the array
Node*[4] connections; //An array of pointers to nodes this current node connects to
Node* parent;
int gScore;
int hScore;
int fScore;
}


class AStar
{
private:
bool[Node] closedList;  

Node currentNode;           //The current node being processed

Node[] Path;        //The path found;

const int connectionCost = 10;

Node start, end;

//.... other functions omitted here//

public:
void FindPath( vect2 vStart, vect2 vEnd, Node[] PathGraph )
{
    Node[] a;
    a.length = 3000;
    auto openList = BinaryHeap!(Node[], "a.fScore > b.fScore")(a, 0);
    closedList.clear;

    SetStartAndEndNode( vStart, vEnd, PathGraph );
    SetStartScores( start );
    openList.insert( start );

    while( currentNode.position != end.position )
    {
        currentNode = openList.front();
        openList.removeFront();

        if( currentNode.position == end.position )
            break;
        else
        {
            closedList[currentNode] = false;

            for( int i = 0; i < currentNode.connections.length; i++ )
            {
                if( currentNode.connections[i] is null )
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    if( IsInList( closedList, *currentNode.connections[i] ) 
                       && currentNode.gScore < currentNode.connections[i].gScore )
                    {
                        currentNode.connections[i].gScore = currentNode.gScore + connectionCost;
                        currentNode.connections[i].fScore = currentNode.connections[i].gScore + currentNode.connections[i].hScore;
                        currentNode.connections[i].parent = &currentNode;
                    }
                    else if( IsInList( a, *currentNode.connections[i] ) 
                            && currentNode.gScore < currentNode.connections[i].gScore )
                    {
                        currentNode.connections[i].gScore = currentNode.gScore + connectionCost;
                        currentNode.connections[i].fScore = currentNode.connections[i].gScore + currentNode.connections[i].hScore;
                        currentNode.connections[i].parent = &currentNode;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        currentNode.connections[i].gScore = currentNode.gScore + connectionCost;
                        currentNode.connections[i].hScore = abs( currentNode.connections[i].xIndex - end.xIndex ) 
                            + abs( currentNode.connections[i].yIndex - end.yIndex );
                        currentNode.connections[i].fScore = currentNode.connections[i].gScore + currentNode.connections[i].hScore;
                        currentNode.connections[i].parent = &currentNode;
                        openList.insert(  *currentNode.connections[i] );
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    writeln( "Current Node Position: ", currentNode.position );
    writeln( "End Node Position: ", end.position );

    //if( currentNode.position == end.position )
    //{
    //    //writeln( "Current Node Parent: ", currentNode.parent );
    //   //GeneratePath();
    //   //ReversePath();
    //}
}
```

}

This is my first attempt at A* so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check my answer here: maybe you get an idea what's wrong :http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26512/how-do-i-make-a-check-all-diagonal-and-orthogonal-directions/26515#26515

Comment: Have you tried adding debugging code so you can see the paths that it's trying to make?  Or stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I've been battling with various issues like nodes not being added to lists, and out of range errors. Right now it looks like after it cycles through and finds the end node, it doesn't save the parent node. So when I went to retrieve the path, I get an error because i'm trying to deference a null pointer. It took a while to get to this point because of all the cryptic errors I was getting. Next I was going to reference the example code I was looking at, and look to see what I'm missing.

Comment: For some reason gScores, hScores, fScores and parent nodes are not updating. So essentially, all of the scores are 0, since D auto-initializes them, which means that my algorithm is broken. Another one of the problems was that I forgot that structs use value semantics, so when I tried to alter values when passing the struct through a function it didn't work. Fixed that by changing to passing the reference.

Comment: Sounds like your learning a new language in a complex situation. I suggest you simplify the algorithm to its barebones and then debug it *verbosely*.

Comment: +1 for using D, its a great language. I'll give A* a shot in it tonight to compare.

Comment: Efficient A* _must_ be done with data structures like priority queues and sets where low element removal and membership checks can be done in sub-linear time. _Not simple lists._ Until you do this, it's debatable whether it's even properly called A*. This is the #1 error I've seen in dozens of A* implementations over the past decade, and it's the same error here. (Among probably many others.)

Comment: @RedShft How far are the distances are we talking about? And how big is the map? A* does slow down the further you get from the target, one game I did I kept the search to only a certain number of searches, mostly this looked ok, sometimes the npc would wonder into a corner, but I thought it added to the realism.

Comment: @PhilCK The map is at most 2500 tiles right now. So probably not big at all. I was just a bit concerned because I read that euclidean distance and Manhattan distance aren't that great for indoor environments.

Comment: @RedShft I would have thought that the Manhattan heuristic would be fine for that size.

For problems like this I'd benchmark portions of the code.

Comment: To figure out whether the heuristic is the problem, try an empty map (no obstacles), find a path from one corner to the other, and count the number of times through the main loop. It should be roughly the length of the path, not looking at all tiles.

Comment: Also, I don't know D — is `IsInList` a built-in, or did you write it? Is it scanning the list or is it random access?

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, simplify your algorithm. It's ok to make a crude implementation and use interpolation to smooth it out later. Maybe also increase the size of each search block and if something is past a certain distance, don't pathfind. And it would probably be best if you cache your path unless your position changes and only recalc if the player moves away from the path.

Comment: Good advices. Also, if performance is still an issue *after* all this, an idea could be to do the pathfinding in a separate thread.